# How do I get the Day of Week order to start with Monday

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a sales table and want to get the day of week for the orders and the number of orders placed on each day of the week. Everything seems to work but no matter what I try the 'week' is non standard. I've tried SET DATEFIRST 1; but still do not get the results I want.

```
SELECT DATENAME(Weekday,orderdate) AS Weekday, COUNT(orderid) AS NumOrders
FROM Sales.Orders
GROUP BY DATENAME(Weekday,orderdate);
```

The results:

```
 Weekday     |    NumOrders
   1. Wednesday      25
   2. Saturday       33
   3. Monday         100
   4. Sunday         115
   5. Thursday       87
   6. Tuesday        42
```

Could the no orders for Friday be causing the output not to order by start of week? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT DATENAME(Weekday, orderdate) AS Weekday, COUNT(orderid) AS NumOrders
FROM Sales.Orders
GROUP BY DATENAME(Weekday, orderdate), DATEPART(Weekday, orderdate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(Weekday, orderdate);
```

Comment: Geez, i'm an idiot I was confusing myself with the DATEPART returning integers. That was the solution...Much appreciated!